# C# - Unit testing Factory Design Pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm working on a project and I have to Unit Test a Factory Design pattern in C#.
Currently im stuck and I have no idea what I have too do. Can someone help me out? I want to Unit Test this code:

```
public class CinemaFactory : AbstractFactory //inheritance of AbstractFactory
{
    public override Space createspace(AddItemsInProps item)
    {
        //returns new Cinema
        return new Cinema(item.AreaType, item.Position, item.Dimension); 
    }
}
```

I also made a Unit test project and created this:

```
    [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Arrange
        Game1.Design_Patterns.CinemaFactory cinemaFactory = new Game1.Design_Patterns.CinemaFactory();

        //Act

        //Assert

    }
}
```

Cinema:

```
public class Cinema : Space //inheritance of Space class
{

    //Named arguments free you from the need to remember or to look up the order of parameters in the parameter lists of called methods. 
    public Cinema(string areaType, string position, string dimension) : base(areaType, position, dimension)
    {
        //The sprite  of the Cinema
        this.Img = "cinema";
    }
    public void StartMovie()
    {

    }
}
```

This is de class AddItemsInProps:

```
public class AddItemsInProps
{
    //Get: The get { } implementation must include a return statement. It can access any member on the class.
    //Set: The set { } implementation receives the implicit argument "value." This is the value to which the property is assigned.

        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public string AreaType { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Dimension { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is de class Space:

```
 public abstract class Space
{
    public string AreaType { get; set; }
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public Point Dimension { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Img { get; set; }
    public int Afstand { get; set; }
    public Space Vorige { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Space, int> Neighbours = new Dictionary<Space, int>();
```

This is de class AbstractFactory:

```
    public abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    //Creating Object
    public abstract Space createspace(AddItemsInProps item);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to test?

Comment: Hi, i want to test if the Factory CinemaFactory  returns  return new Cinema(item.AreaType, item.Position, item.Dimension). I have no idea how i can test it

Comment: Do you have permissions to edit your post? Please add the definitions of `AddItemsInProps`, `Cinema`, `Space` and `AbstractFactory` - basically everything that is needed to compile the code

Comment: added a test example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an instance of the subject under test and provide the necessary dependencies.

```
[TestClass]
public class CinemaFactorTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void CinemaFactory_Should_Create_Cinema() {
        //Arrange
        var cinemaFactory = new Game1.Design_Patterns.CinemaFactory();

        var item = new AddItemsInProps {
            //set necessary properties here
            AreaType = "value here",
            Position = "value here",
            Dimension = "value here"
        };

        //Act
        var actual = cinemaFactory.createspace(item);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(Cinema));
        //...you can also compare property values from item and actual for equality
        Assert.AreEqual(item.AreaType, actual.AreaType);
        //...
    }
}
```

Invoke the method under test and then verify the expected behavior with the actual behavior

Comment: I have no idea what I can put in the "var item = new AddItemsInProps" can you help me out with that

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can test, such as the type of the object returned by the factory and also if the object is equivalent to an expected object.

An example - testing the equivalence:

```
[TestClass]
public class CinemaFactoryTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenItemProps_WhenCreatingSpace_ShouldReturnExpectedSpace()
    {
        // arrange
        var factory = new CinemaFactory();

        var props = new AddItemsInProps
        {
            AreaType = "my area",
            Position = "my position",
            Dimension = "my dimension"
        };

        // act
        Space cinema = factory.createspace(props);

        // assert
        var expectedCinema = new Cinema(props.AreaType, props.Position, props.Dimension);
        cinema.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCinema);
    }
}
```

In this case I'm checking if the object returned by the factory is equivalent to the one expected.

PS: I'm using [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/) to check if the objects are equivalent.

Comment: The " cinema.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedCinema);" doesnt work in C#, do you have another line of code how it will works?

Comment: @user9554749 I'm using FluentAssertions nuget package, that contains more and better assertions compared to MsTest or NUnit. I just realised you're using MSTest (not NUnit), I'll edit my answer soon

Comment: That would be great. Thanks, i will install the FluentAssertions nuget package

Comment: @user9554749 edited my answer, it is now using MsTest and FluentAssertions.